# Postgres json_build_object adding backslash to text column

Tags: json, postgresql

I am doing a select from a table and I want the output to be in json. For this I am using the json_build_object function.

I am getting some unexpected behavior when the select has a value with a slash inside of it.
A simple example would be:

```
select json_build_object('test', 'a\b');
```

This outputs:

```
{ "test": "a\\b" }
```

I would like to get an output of:

```
{ "test": "a\b" } // without extra backslash
```

Comment: I suspect that `{ "test": "a\b" }` is not valid JSON. Why don't you want the escaping character?

Comment: Maybe he needs a backspace character... BTW you have to specify it as `E'a\b'`...

Comment: @GMB
I am storing some encoded strings that can contain backslashes and I want to have the same number of slashes when I get the data out with a select

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is three characters including the first two letters and a literal backslash between them, then `"a\\b"` is the correct way to represent that in JSON.

If your input were made up of 2 characters, the first letter and the 'backspace' control character, that would correctly be represented in JSON as `"a\b"`.  But that is not the input you showed us.  If your input is not what you want it to be, you shouldn't expect json_build_object to read your mind and fix it for you.

Comment: Does JSON really require the backslash to be escaped?

Comment: If you want it to be a literal backslash and not the introduction of an escape sequence, yes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Yes.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-7  All Unicode characters may be placed within the
   quotation marks, except for the characters that must be escaped:
   quotation mark, **reverse solidus**, and the control characters (U+0000
   through U+001F).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks